# C thread argument

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

Basic function of my program: create number of counters (0), create number of instructions per threads, create the struct instructions which contain counter*, repetitions and work_fn (increment, decrement etc).
Program will build all the dynamic structure (already coded up)
then spawn threads and join. One thread can have more than one instructions.

```
static void* worker_thread(void *arg){
  long long *n;
  pthread_mutex_lock( &lock1 );

  n = (long long *) arg;
  printf("Testing: %lld.\n", n);

  pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock1 );

  return NULL;
}

//nthreads is the total number of threads

for(int i=0; i < nthreads ; i++){
  pthread_create( &thread_id[i], NULL, worker_thread, &i); //Problem
}


for(int i=0; i < nthreads ; i++){
  pthread_join( thread_id[i], NULL);
}
```

I am trying to test the thread function, firstly create number of threads then join them.
But I can't seems to pass the current thread number [i] in my case to the worker thread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = (int)arg;
```

In your worker_thread function.

And

```
(void*)i
```

Instead of `&i` in your thread spawn

Comment: For some reason I am getting the address printed out instead

Comment: Thanks!but i got a warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size from main function

Comment: i did have long long n = (long long)arg; and (void *)i tho =\

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
(void *) i
```

in pthread_create

and then

```
int i = (int) arg
```

Comment: Thanks got it, but i got a warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size from gcc in the function 'main'

Comment: Check please, is sizeof(int)==sizeof(void*) on your platform

Comment: Your problem is that you're compiling in 64bits. Try launching a `file your_executable`, it should tell you it's x86_64. 2 solutions: use the `-m32` when compiling your code, or convert your _int_ to a _long  int_.

Comment: Or turn off the bogus gcc warnings.